# Long press Android inside Application

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to simulate long taps on an Android device using ADB.

I read this guide: http://ktnr74.blogspot.it/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

And I knew that it works on the UI of Android but it doesn't work inside an application.

In particular, I'm trying to simulate long-taps on a text field of an Application.

Comment: Have you set LongPressListener to textfield ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: First of all you will need root for this. To ask for root in runtime:

```
public static Process requestPermission() {
    try {
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("The phone needs root: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Process process = SystemUtils.requestPermission();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

cmd = "/system/bin/input swipe 100 1650 600 1650\n"; //Example

os.writeBytes(cmd);
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
process.waitFor();
```

The commands and default sources are:

```
text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
press (Default: trackball)
roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
```

You can find the "adb shell keyevent" commands [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: The question is about sending long tap from the adb to the device. Your answer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: yeah the question was about sending long tap from adb to device. But fortunately it is possible by use the command adb shell input touchscreen swipe x y x y 2000 where 2000 is 2000ms. I was wrong coordinates (they were relative rather than absolute). Thank you all!!!